# How to check if an element classList contains a string or word partially?

Tags: javascript, class, contains

I've got this code:

```js
const all = document.querySelectorAll('div');
let variable = 'fruits';

all.forEach((item) => {
  if(item.classList.contains(variable)) {
   item.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="fruits">
  Fruits
</div>

<div class="fruits-green">
  Green fruits
</div>
```

and I was wondering if theres to use classList.contains with a string/word partially?

Obviously what I'm trying to achieve is to get fruits-green styled too, since it contains **fruits**-green

I know there are CSS selectors for that, but given that my fruits variable will change with other JS functions, I'd like this to be vanilla JS too.

Any advice is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: [`document.querySelectorAll('div[class*=fruits]')`](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/koaqrgbu/)?

Comment: @DavidThomas as I mentioned fruits is a variable that will change, so I can't use CSS selectors

for example:
variable fruits I want to also trigger fruits-#whateverWordMayFollow#
variable vegetables I want to also trigger vegetables-#whateverWordMayFollow#

Comment: I'd suggest giving more information about your use-case, problem and enough "*[mcve]*" code to adequately demonstrate the problem you're facing, because different variables can certainly be incorporated into a `document.querySelectorAll()` call.

Comment: @DavidThomas you're right! that was my bad. I had an issue somewhere else which was confusing me, but I got it working using  document.querySelectorAll('div[class*="' + variable + '"]');
Thanks man!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `classList` property is a `DOMTokenList` which is a string but has methods and properties simular to Array methods.

- Iterate through the array of tags (`all`). We'll use `.flatMap()` because we are dealing with multiple tags that may or may not have multiple matches.

  ```
  all.flatMap((div, idx) => {//...
  ```
- Next, we'll use the `.value` property of `classList` which returns a space delimited string of each of the tag's classes.

  ```
  let list = div.classList.value.split(' ');
  ```
- Then we'll `.filter()` each class of each tag by comparing with `.includes()`

  ```
  list.filter(cls => cls.toLowerCase().includes('fruit'));
  ```
- Finally, an array of arrays is returned. Each sub-array contains a tag's matching classes.

  ```js
  const all = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div'));

  let output = all.flatMap((div, idx) => {
    let list = div.classList.value.split(' ');
    console.log(list)
    let matches = list.filter(cls => cls.toLowerCase().includes('fruit'));
    return [matches];
  })

  console.log(output);
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="fruits fries">
    Fruits fries
  </div>

  <div class="fruits-green fruity">
    Green fruits fruit
  </div>
  ```

Comment: thanks for all the info man! much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work using

```js
let variable = 'fruits';
const all = document.querySelectorAll('div[class*="'+variable+'"]');

all.forEach((item) => {
  item.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

```html
<div class="fruits">
  Fruits
</div>

<div class="fruits-green">
  Green fruits
</div>
```

Thanks again @David